# Remove CR & LF from the end of a string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I send a customer PowerShell scripts to export AD data to CSV. They send me the CSV files. I import those into an analytic tool called WeGalvanice ACL (ACL for short). Within ACL I filter/match/compare and whatever I need doing.

I want to use those results and put them in a .docx file.
ACL can't export to docx, only xlsx/txt/csv/html/json/del.

To work around that (or so I thought), I made a `template.docx`. Within that `template.docx` I wrote the placeholders like `%certainvariable%`.
Within ACL I created a command to write all variables I need to files called `%variablename%.txt`. Within the txt is the value I need.

For example:
ACL creates `disabledusers.txt`.
If you open the txt it only shows 10, meaning we got 10 disabled users.

I tried to create a VBA macro to import the txt files and use the contained values to replace the according `%...%` text within the Word document.

I noticed I got `20` followed by that box that means "I have no clue how to display this char".

Prior to running the script:
[image: picture prior to running the script]

After running the script:
[image: picture after running the script]

Picture of .txt content that I import:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/Aa90Ek4.png]

The VBS code from Word Macro manager (for convenience I only uploaded one import-and-replace job. In my script I copied this 30 times for each file and variable):

```vb
Sub ACL()
    ' ACL Macro

    FilePath = "local folderpath\date.txt"
    TextFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
    new_date = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    old_date = "%date%"
    Close TextFile

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute findtext:=old_date, replacewith:=new_date, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With    
End Sub
```

When I open the `date.txt` manually and remove the second line then it all seems to work. But I want it automated.

I tried

- Adding `split textfile,/n` and `split new_date,/n` both with `\n\r` and `\r`.
- SED commands to remove second line.
- Found plenty of findstr methods to remove carriage return (crlf)
  but either my txt files where suddenly empty, or I still got the boxes in my Word file.

---

Thanks to Tomalak I got the principle working:

```vb
' removes CR & LF from the end of a string (not pretty but gets the job done)
Function TrimRight(InputStr As String) As String
    While Right(InputStr, 1) = vbCr Or Right(InputStr, 1) = vbLf
        InputStr = Left(InputStr, Len(InputStr) - 1)
    Wend
    TrimRight = Trim(InputStr)
End Function


' reads any text file and returns the content as-is
Function ReadFile(FilePath As String) As String
    Dim filenum As Integer
    
  If Dir(FilePath) > "" Then
        filenum = FreeFile
        Open FilePath For Input As filenum
        ReadFile = Input(LOF(filenum), filenum)
        Close filenum
    Else
        Debug.Print "File not found: " & FilePath
    End If
End Function


' replaces all instances of a single word in the given document
Sub ReplaceAll(oldValue As String, newValue As String, doc As Document)
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute findtext:=oldValue, replacewith:=newValue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub


Sub ReplaceAllVariables()
    Dim variables As Variant, variable As Variant
    Dim placeholder As String, realValue As String

    variables = Split("customer,c_adgroup,c_adgroup_Cannot_change_PW,c_adgroup_disabled,c_adgroup_enabled,c_adgroup_expire_and_disabled,c_adgroup_LockedOut,c_adgroup_Locked_and_disabled,c_adgroup_loginx,c_adgroup_loginx_disabled,c_adgroup_nolastpasswordset,c_adgroup_nologondate,c_adgroup_PWRQ_and_disabled,c_adgroup_PWx,c_adgroup_PWx_and_disabled,c_adgroup_PW_and_disabled,c_adgroup_PW_and_enabled,c_adgroup_PWRQ_and_enabled ,c_adgroup_PW_not_required,c_adgroup_PW_no_expire,c_adgroup_loginx_and_enabled,c_adusers_f_Cannot_change_PW,c_adusers_f_disabled,c_adusers_f_enabled,c_adusers_f_expire_and_disabled,c_adusers_f_LockedOut,c_adusers_f_Locked_and_disabled,c_adusers_f_loginx,c_adusers_f_loginx_disabled,c_adusers_f_nolastpasswordset,c_adusers_f_nologondate,c_adusers_f_PWRQ_and_disabled,c_adusers_f_PWx,c_adusers_f_PWx_and_disabled,c_adusers_f_PW_and_disabled,c_adusers_f_PW_not_required,c_adusers_f_PW_no_expire,c_adusers_f_loginx_and_enabled,date,c_adusers_f_PW_and_enabled,lastlogon", ",")

    For Each variable In variables
        placeholder = "%" & variable & "%"
        realValue = ReadFile("C:\Users\jerryw\Documents\Klanten\ACL\AD analyse\var\" & variable & ".txt")
        realValue = TrimRight(realValue)
        ReplaceAll placeholder, realValue, ActiveDocument
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: From Help _Ever since the first version of Visual Basic, files have been processed using the Open statement and other related statements and functions (listed below). These mechanisms will eventually be phased out in favor of the FSO object model, but they are fully supported in Visual Basic 6.0._.

Comment: PS that comment is 25 years old.

Comment: Additionally to this deprecation warning, `Open` will mess up the data when the txt file is in an unexpected encoding (e.g. UTF-8). You'll see when there is text with accented characters if things are working out in your case or not.

Comment: FWIW, if you change a .txt file's extension to .doc, Word will open it as a Word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the newline (CRLF). You have to get rid of it.

And while we are at it, let's also get rid of the *"I've copied that code 30 times"* bit, that's a horrible way to solve this problem. Loops are better.

Helpers:

```
' removes CR & LF from the end of a string (not pretty but gets the job done)
Function TrimRight(InputStr As String) As String
    While Right(InputStr, 1) = vbCr Or Right(InputStr, 1) = vbLf
        InputStr = Left(InputStr, Len(InputStr) - 1)
    Wend
    TrimRight = Trim(InputStr)
End Function

' reads any text file and returns the content as-is
Function ReadFile(FilePath As String) As String
    Dim filenum As Integer

    If Dir(FilePath) > "" Then
        filenum = FreeFile
        Open FilePath For Input As filenum
        ReadFile = Input(LOF(filenum), filenum)
        Close filenum
    Else
        Debug.Print "File not found: " & FilePath
    End If
End Function

' replaces all instances of a single word in the given document
Sub ReplaceAll(oldValue As String, newValue As String, doc As Document)
    With doc.content.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute findtext:=oldValue, replacewith:=newValue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Worker:

```
Sub ReplaceAllVariables()
    Dim variables As Variant, variable As Variant
    Dim placeholder As String, realValue As String

    variables = Split("date,disabledusers,and,any,other,variable,you,have", ",")

    For Each variable In variables
        placeholder = "%" & variable & "%"
        realValue = ReadFile("\local folderpath\" & variable & ".txt")
        realValue = TrimRight(realValue)
        ReplaceAll placeholder, realValue, ActiveDocument
    Next
End Sub
```

The `TrimRight()` function only strips the *final* line break from the given input string. Any line breaks that are in the middle of the content are retained. If this is a thing that can happen with your data, Word will create new paragraphs for every `LF` it finds. And it will draw boxes for every `CR` it finds.

If you do have multi-line txt files, but don't want new paragraphs, and don't want boxes, either, modify the content of the text file before you use it (get rid of CRs, replace the LFs with vertical tabs, which are Word's way to represent "soft breaks", i.e. the same thing you get with Shift+Enter):

```
realValue = ReadFile("\local folderpath\" & variable & ".txt")
realValue = TrimRight(realValue)
realValue = Replace(Replace(realValue, vbCr, ""), vbLf, vbVerticalTab)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer tomalak, 
and i totaly agree with you that pasting the import 30 times is ugly and less efficient, but with lack on coding experiance it was the best i could come up with ;)

currently i dont have the code nor files with me, will test with this tomorrow

am i correct to assume i need to change filepath to the folder containing all variable.txt files?
and then add all variable names to the split command.

anything else i should add or change?

Thanks for this spend most of today on getting this part to work and still failed xD

Comment: Pretty much - adapt the paths, add your variable names. But make sure that you understand how all of this works before you use it. It helps to set breakpoints in the VBA IDE (F9)and step through the code line-wise (F8), while looking at variable values (View -> Locals Window).

Comment: tomalak, 

i am trying your code now, it removes all the %variable% from the word document but does not replace them with anything else.
i added a         MsgBox (variable)  to the end, and it does give me popups with all the variable names     "date, disabledusers ect"    
also i notice that the when i open view>locals window i dont see any value's to the variables.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox`, it's much less annoying (switch on the Immediate Window to see output from `Debug.Print`). I can't see anything wrong with the code as I wrote it, are you sure you have not made any changes to it?

Comment: only changes i made sofar are:
        If Dir("C:\Users\jerryw\Documents\Klanten\ACL\AD analyse\var") > "" 
ill change the other variables once this works ;)
picture of current code> https://i.imgur.com/TEn4OGl.png
so you can see it as is

Comment: when i look at the local var i see realvalue as "" as seen in picture: https://i.imgur.com/z0s3z0Q.png
so im guessing that the value in the .txt files aint imported propperly?

Comment: indeed the debug.print gives way better information ;)


   'File not found: C:\Users\jerryw\Documents\Klanten\ACL\AD analyse\var\
    File not found: C:\Users\jerryw\Documents\Klanten\ACL\AD analyse\var\'

Comment: Think about that for a while. You have made changes to my code.

Comment: went back to your original code, 
no changes
i get:    File not found: \local folderpath\date.txt
File not found: \local folderpath\disabledusers.txt

word document is not in the same folder as the txt files,  thus i added filepath = C:\Users\jerryw\Documents\Klanten\ACL\AD analyse\var\   but gives me same error,

Comment: Fixed!  had to replace \local folderpath instead of filepath ;P

Comment: Good work. :) I hope you threw out all the superfluous copies of your code, too!

Comment: Tomalak, 

sofar it all seems to work like a charm! many thanks ;)
is there a way to split the split command in 2 ? since i have quite a list of variables im very close to the limit.
and i know i want to create more variables.
or should i just make 2 scripts both with there own txt folder and variables?

Comment: Yes, the underscore `_` is the line continuation character in VB. It must be preceded by a space and followed by a line-break. You can use it to break up any statement/expression that otherwise would have to be on a single line. However you can't use it inside strings but pretty much everywhere else. To break up long strings you can use `"string part 1" & _<line-break here>"string part 2"`

Comment: You could also make a `_variables_.txt` with one variable per line, and use `variables = Split(ReadFile("\path\to\_variables_.txt"), vbCrLf)`. This way you would not have to change your code to add or remove variables.